# Blender to Unity, Animations are exporting 2x

Tags: animation, export, import, unity

My animations are exporting under (armature | animation-name) and (animation-name). This goes for each animation I made so it takes double the space. Is there any way to export them from blender to unity only once?

[image: Armature|Idle]

[image: Idle]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the only way I know of doing this is putting al of your animations in the NLA window. Like so.

[image]

After that you can export the Armature + Model.

Deselect - All actions

Select - NLA Strips ( in which you put the animations )

[image]

That way, when you import it into unity you will only get the animations that were pushed down on the NLA strip.

[image]